# customize bootstrap email form field validation

Tags: regex, django, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use a bootstrap form email field validation on frontend

```
form.validate({
  rules: {
    emails: {
      emails: true
      }
    }
  })
```

And an `EmailField` on backend using `Django`. I've found a regexp bug in bootstrap validation:

- typing email@name.d does validate email
- on the backend `Django` says the email is wrong

Question is: How to apply custom form email validation using bootstrap? All I need is to set my own regexp. I could get rid of bootstrap validation tho, but there are some useful styling on `success` and `error` which I don't really want rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create ajax post request with email in it. On backed evaluate your email and return response in JSON. Parse JSON on frontend and see if email is validate or not.

**EDIT**

I guess that you are using bootstrapvalidator, so you can override emailAddress.js and implement it by your own. Also you can just change their current regex which is

```
var emailRegExp   = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```